# no se muestra los estilos al ver o descargar pdf con DOMPDF en laravel con vista blade

Tags: pdf, laravel-blade, laravel-8, dompdf

Estoy intentando ver y descargar un pdf a partir de una vista blade. Si abro la vista normal se ve los estilos y la estructura pero en pdf se pierde.

Este es mi controlador donde tengo la funcion para ver o descargar el pdf

```
public function historia($id){

        $historias=Seguimiento::with('paciente')->with('user')->where('paciente_id',$id)->get();
      
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('exports.historia', compact('historias');

        return $pdf->stream('historia.pdf');

        // return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');

   }
```

Ruta

```
Route::get('export/historia{id}',[SeguimientoController::class, 'historia'])->name('seguimientos.historia');
```

Boton donde ejecuto la funcion

```
<a href="{{ route('seguimientos.historia', $pa->id) }}" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Ver en PDF">
 <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
</button>
</a>
```

archivo vista `historia.blade.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Historia</title>
    <style>
        @page {
            margin: 0cm 0cm;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        body {
            margin: 3cm 2cm 2cm;
        }

        header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0cm;
            left: 0cm;
            right: 0cm;
            height: 2cm;
            background-color: #2a0927;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 30px;
        }

        footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0cm;
            left: 0cm;
            right: 0cm;
            height: 2cm;
            background-color: #2a0927;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 35px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>


    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/todomed.png') }}" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="row col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <p class="text-center">HISTORIA REPORTE PSICOLOGICO</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sede">
                                identificacion
                            </label>
                             <p>148596</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sede">
                                identificacion
                            </label>
                             <p>148596</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sede">
                                identificacion
                            </label>
                             <p>148596</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <h1>Contenido</h1>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <h1>www.styde.net</h1>
    </footer>



    {{-- paginacion --}}
    <script type="text/php">
        if ( isset($pdf) ) {
                $pdf->page_script('
                    $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", "normal");
                    $pdf->text(270, 730, "Pagina $PAGE_NUM de $PAGE_COUNT", $font, 10);
                ');
            }
        </script>
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

cuando cargo la anterior vista normalmente tiene esta estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al cargarlo o descargarlo en pdf me lo muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna manera que se pueda ver tal cual como en la vista blade?

Comment: Lo que te falla es la carga de bootstrap y luego su interpretación por parte de DOMPdf, no es totalmente compatible con bootstrap-4. Puedes probar bootstrap-3 incluyendo todo el contenido de bootstrap.min.css dentro de la etiqueta <style> de la vista. **O mejor aún** [no uses bootstrap](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/discussions/2473).

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ¿bootstrap-3? es compatible con dompdf?

Comment: @FreddyDaniel No totalmente, pero a mí me ha funcionado por lo menos para hacer una grilla simple con las clases class="row" y class="col". Como mencionan en el link que puse en el comentario anterior, "Hay una serie de problemas que tendremos que abordar..."

Comment: Creo que es por el uso de html5 con css3 lo que no entiende esa librería. Deberías hacerlo a la antigua.